# How to get total number of users from a Telegram group and display those stats in simple html text?

Tags: javascript, api, telegram

I am trying to find the API endpoint for telegram... a public one that does not require any login or API keys...

I found this: https://core.telegram.org/schema/json which includes a long JSON list of functions. Not sure if there are other API endpoints that can be used to query just a group and show stats for that group or how exactly to go about it.

I have seen other users suggest creating a telegram bot and then pull this data from the bot however not sure exactly how to do this effectively.

The main goal is to simply display the total users of a group via javascript and add the number via `<span id="telegram-users">1</span>`

I have seen this being done on coingecko's coins and token listings under social however can not figure out how to simply show the total number of a telegram group in simple HTML format from JSON data for API..

UPDATE:

I did some research and freshened up on my coding skills.

There is this website: https://tgstat.com/ that pulls data for telegram channels. I am trying to use a simple javascript function to `fetch` this url and then use `jsoup` to get the data by using the element identifier which is `.columns.large-2.medium-4.small-6.margin-bottom15 > div > .align-center > #text`

Then use `document.getElementById("telegram-members").innerHTML = ()`

to display this data in html.

I understand the cosp and will use https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url= to bypass this.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to send a HTTP GET request to get the data without using any module? Like the Telegram API module for nodejs.

Comment: @Justsomesailboat I updated the question to add more details on what I am trying to do. Thanks for your comment / requesting more info

Comment: it does not have to be with jsoup or even fetch. it can be jqury but essentially i just need the member count that is being kept on the tgstat.com site to display the number of members in a particular group in simple plain html.

Comment: For example, this url https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://tgstat.com/en/channel/@addStickers to just get the data of number above "members". The identifier is in the original question. I am just having trouble with my code as I was using this: https://regroove.ca/archive/2013/03/21/how-to-pull-content-via-jquery-from-another-web-site-cross-domain-and-do-it-in-sharepoint-too/ but that method seems to be outdated or the formatting of the "" is messing everything up on my end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, if I understand your question well. You're trying to get the total number of users from a telegram group, channel, or chat.

The premise is, you want to avoid using Telegram API which will require auth token.
However, since your main goal is just basically the same. I'll leave this method here, so you'll have a "backup plan" later.

> **Requirement & Notes:**
>
> - Create a bot on Telegram app, and get the bot token.
> - For tracking channels, you just need to find the `@channel` name.
> - However for group chats, you need to find the **chat_id** for it. As explained below!
> - Only vanilla Javascript is needed
> - A bit of patience

At most usage, you just need to send a HTTP request to the Telegram API.

API Example: `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token-here>?<api-method-here>`

You can learn more about other API method [Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

#### Hold Up!

Firstly, what do you want to track? Is it **a group?** Is it **a channel?**

**Both have different method**, please check out the example below!.

---

##### To track the number of members that are following a channel

This is fairly easy. Just send a HTTP request to:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot<token-here>/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=<channel-name>`

For example: the name of the official telegram channel is `@telegram`.

Sooo, send a request to:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot<token-here>/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=@telegram`

You'll get a response like:

```
{ ok: true, result: 5605541 }
```

The total number of followers is shown in the `result` key.

---

##### To track the number of members in a group chat

Before we can get the number of members in a group. You need to find the **<chat_id>** for your group chat.

*Note: Your bot must join the group before you can do anything like tracking, send message etc.*

To do that, send a HTTP request to `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token-here>/getUpdates`.

Look closely into the response. You need to find the `chat` object, like this.

```
<...>
​​
0: Object { update_id: 122334455, my_chat_member: {…} }
​​​
my_chat_member: Object { chat: {…}, from: {…}, date: 1622275487, … }
​​​​
chat: Object { id: -1234567890, title: "Group-Name", type: "group", … }

<...>
```

You just need the `id` from the `chat` object. Which is `-1234567890` in this case.

**After** you got the `chat_id` number.

Just send a HTTP request to:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot<token-here>/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=<id-number>`

You'll also get the response as:

```
{ ok: true, result: 3 }
```

The number of members is stored in the `result` key. Just parse it out and boom!

---

**Full Example**

- **hello.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <span id="telegram-users">null</span>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script src="hello.js"></script>
</html>
```

- **hello.js**

```
// Set Your Bot Token Here
var Token = "insert_your_bot_token";

/*
   chat_id for the group or channel you want to track,
   For channels, they are usually like @telegram, @Bitcoin_News_Crypto, @TelegramTips,
   For group chats, they are numbers alike. Just like "-1234567890",
   Modify and set your chat_id here if you found it,
   It should look like var group_chat_id = "-1234567890".
*/
var chat_id = "@telegram";

// HTTP Request Function
function httpRequest(URL, Method)
{
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.open(Method, URL, false);
      xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlHttp.send(null);
      return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
}

// Send a request to Telegram API to get number of members in a particular group or channel
function getMemberCount()
{
      return httpRequest(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${Token}/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=${chat_id}`, "GET");
}

// Run function and parse only the number of members
var result = getMemberCount()["result"];
console.log(result);

// Write the numbers of member back to HTML
document.getElementById("telegram-users").innerText = `The group or channel currently has ${result} members.`;

// Use this to find the *chat_id* for your group chat
//console.log(httpRequest(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${Token}/getUpdates`, "GET"));
```

Comment: This for sure did the trick for what I needed. I know its with the api key, but there does not seem like a reasonable way around it. Additionally your solution did not just provide text documentation but also showed an example which is so vital. I wanted to say thank you for this!

Comment: I have tried the Telegram API method (GetFullChannelRequest) and Bot Api method list above side by side against each other and found that the Telegram API way is more accurate. When I join and unjoin a channel, the number of subscribers immediately changes, but for the Bot API it doesn't change immediately (actually looks like it updates on the minute), so if you need to monitor number of subscribers more accurately, go with the Telegram API.....Also, you can use -100<chat-id> or <channel_name> when getting data for a channel

Answer (score 0):

This question has been moved here for easier understanding of the issue. [How to pull data from another website using Javascript or jQuery (cross-domain) CORS (no api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749181/how-to-pull-data-from-another-website-using-javascript-or-jquery-cross-domain-c)