# How to pull data from another website using Javascript or jQuery (cross-domain) CORS (no api)

Tags: javascript, fetch, jsoup, telegram

The goal is to get the total number of members in the telegram group. This number has a unique css identifier and should be able to get pulled via jsoup or another method..

Using telegram api requires auth tokens and using this method I am trying to work around any api keys that could end up getting used elsewhere as this code will be used on an open source project and could have the keys end up being leaked.

I am trying to pull data from this website: `https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://tgstat.com/en/channel/@addStickers`

The CSS selector for the total group members is `.columns.large-2.medium-4.small-6.margin-bottom15 > div > .align-center > #text`

The code I am using is a bit outdated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



 fetch('https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://tgstat.com/en/channel/@addStickers').then(function(response) {
 response.html().then(function(members){
    
    members.forEach(function(member){
      document.getElementById("tg-members").innerHTML = (.columns.large-2.medium-4.small-6.margin-bottom15 > div > .align-center > #text)
    });
  });
}).catch(err => console.error(err));


 </script>
```

I know I am doing something wrong just not sure exactly. Any help is appreciated.

It does not have to be with fetch, could be with jQuery.. essentially I just need to get the number of members in plain html format to be displayed via document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right code to be using, however it just does not pull the number of members as needed. It bypasses the CORS however I don't know how to select the right css for the members so nothing is happening...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var ExternalURL = "tgstat.com/en/channel/@addStickers"; // This address must not contain any leading "http://"
   var ContentLocationInDOM = ".columns.large-2.medium-4.small-6.margin-bottom15 > div > .align-center > #text"; // If you're trying to get sub-content from the page, specify the "CSS style" jQuery syntax here, otherwise set this to "null"

    $(document).ready(loadContent);
   function loadContent()
   {
      var QueryURL = "https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=" + ExternalURL;
      $.getJSON(QueryURL, function(data){
         if (data && data != null && typeof data == "object" && data.contents && data.contents != null && typeof data.contents == "string")
         {
            data = data.contents.replace();
            if (data.length > 0)
            {
               if (ContentLocationInDOM && ContentLocationInDOM != null && ContentLocationInDOM != "null")
               {
                  $('#telegramMembers').html($(ContentLocationInDOM, data));
               }
               else
               {
                  $('#telegramMembers').html(data);
               }
            }
         }
      });
   }
</script>
```

any suggestions would be helpful.